# How to get "Arbalistic" hidden achievement?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, achievements

How do I get this hidden achievement, "Arbalistic", and what is the best/fastest way to do so?

Answer (score 2):

The following guide is from [Sportskeeda](https://www.sportskeeda.com/minecraft/how-get-arbalistic-advancement-minecraft):

> This hidden achievement is one of the easiest ones to get, and
> involves killing 5 different mobs using a crossbow. Best mobs to use
> are:
>
> - Sheep
> - Pig
> - Chicken
> - Goat
> - Cow
>
> You also need a Piercing IV enchanted Crossbow (at minimum), an iron
> axe, and some building blocks.
>
> To get the process started, players will want to create a hallway that
> is one block wide and six blocks deep, and this will be used to
> accommodate and line up the necessary mobs. Ideally, the hallway
> should be about two blocks high, with the front partially blocked in
> its middle row. A slab should also be placed in the middle to prevent
> smaller mobs from escaping from the middle block.
>
> [image]
>
> Next, Minecraft players will want to place a small 3x1 or 3x2 hole in
> front of the 'kill hallway'. This will allow them to stand in the hole
> and line up their shot through the slot created in the hallway.
>
> Finally, players will need five different animal mobs (duplicates
> won't work, and hostile mobs work as well but are tougher to corral)
> to place within the hallway. Popular picks include chickens, sheep,
> pigs, cows, and goats (using a lead and bringing them into the hallway
> before sealing it off is incredibly helpful in Survival Mode).
>
> Before lining up a shot with their Piercing IV Crossbow, Minecraft
> advancement hunters will also want to take an iron axe and use a
> fully-charged strike to injure their mobs to near-death (chickens and
> sheep typically don't need to be hit, while mobs like llamas may need
> to be hit multiple times).
>
> Once the Minecraft mobs are injured and players have their crossbow at
> the ready, they simply need to stand in the hole and line up their
> shot. Once the arrow is primed, firing it through the center slot
> should kill every mob within the hallway in one shot due to Piercing
> IV's effect.